# Questions about GDPR for AdMob and their UMP SDK for consent form

Tags: ios, admob, gdprconsentform

I have some questions about the GDPR policy on AdMob. I'm not living in EEA and am also not so familiar with the GDPR, so I'd be glad if you can help me.

First of all, if my iOS app is published in the EEA and the app shows the AD via AdMob,

- **We do need** to get GDPR consent, correct?
- **We do need** to get GDPR consent even if we don't show Personalized ADs (by setting the `npa=1` flag to AD request), correct? (Because they use Cookie for other purposes)

Besides, I'm thinking of using Google's UMP (User Messaging Platform) form to get GDPR consent. However, there's no way to retrieve the user's decision at least via Google Mobile Ads SDK, so

- How can I forward consent to the AdMob ADs request as Google mentions [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#forward-consent)? For example, set `npa=1` only when a user doesn't consent to Personalized ADs in the UMP form. Is it impossible?
- Or, if a user doesn't consent to Personalized ADs in the UMP form, AdMob stops personalizing on their end without any publisher's action? (e.g. forwarding the consent to the AdMob ADs request such as the `npa=1` flag on the iOS app?)

Finally, related to the previous last question, in the UMP form, there's a way to disable even Basic Ads,

- Is it the same as Non-Personalized Ads?
- If so, if the user disables both Personalized and Basic Ads in the UMP form, AdMob stops showing any Ads to this user?

[image]

Comment: any updates on this? I have exactly the same questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/issues/274

Comment: It seems that when a user disables personalized ads, you have to pass that info to AdMob (they do not do it for us).

Comment: Also, yes. In the EEA, users can disable even non-personalized ads (basic ads). But don't worry, no one reads policies. You will get >90% consent for the required stuff.

Comment: If a user disables ads, he has the right to use the app for free in Europe. You must not obligate him to grant the consent (it is a GDPR violation).

Comment: @Raul Thank you. So, it seems developers have to forward the consent status to the Google Mobile Ads SDK right? However, as far as I know, there's no way (at least on iOS SDK) to retrieve the user's consent status on the UMP framework. There seems to be "consentStatus" on the "UMPConsentInformation" object, but only 4 of the statuses, and not sure in detail (e.g. whether a user opted out of Personalized Ads only or Basic Ads too)

Comment: I was wrong. Read this. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/pull/278/commits/45c5d144b54c590bdcc47dcff1778d4322563f8c

Comment: @Raul Thank you. That's interesting especially the part "AdMob will automatically handle the request with the consent status selected by the user.". However, it's the case when we set `NPA=1` and I believe we don't have a way to know whether or not users allowed Personalized Ads through UMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the answer to the issue of the `npa=1` after a year.

According to the person from the Mobile Ads SDK Team, the consent results are stored in UserDefaults (SharedPreference in Android) and AdMob SDK uses it without any publishers' additional action.

FYI: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/I6j0Pr-_ziY/m/VOH06zsWAQAJ